# How can I output only the values of subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I want to output some data:

```
array(4) {
  [123]=>
  array(2) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "harry"
  }
  [345]=>
  array(2) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "fred"
  }
  ["animal"]=>
  string(5) "horse"
  ["plant"]=>
  string(4) "tree"
}
```

This is my solution, which I have the feeling is very unsmart:

```
echo "<b>These are all the colors:</b><br>";

foreach ($properties as $key => $val) {
if ($key != "plant" AND $key != "animal"){
echo  $val['color']."<br>";
}
}
echo "<b>This is the animal:</b><br>";              

foreach ($properties as $key => $val) {
if ($key == "animal"){
echo  $val."<br>";
}
}


echo "<b>This is the plant:</b><br>";   

foreach ($properties as $key => $val) {
if ($key == "plant"){
echo  $val."<br>";
}
}
```

It gives me the desired result...

**These are all the colors:**

red

blue

**This is the animal:**

horse

**This is the plant:**

tree

...but I thought maybe you know a more simple solution. I am sure it must be possible to talk only to subarrays, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: this is object try this `$val->color;`

Comment: @jay It's not an object

Comment: wait i run this code than say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since php 5.5, you can use **array_column**:

```
$color = array_column($properties, 'color');
```

Since php 5.3, you can use array_map with an anonymous function, like this:

```
$color = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['color'];}, $properties);

print_r($color);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, Use Switch in foreach and it will help for this problem.

```html
foreach ($properties as $key => $val) {
switch($key){
case '':
break;
}
}
```